# Carousel arrows overlapping above navbar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

I have a site that let the user choose between different layout base on Bootstrap.

[Helloguest.com.au](http://www.helloguest.com.au/web_site_designs.html)

When the carousel is above the navbar, everything works fine (select BannerFirst with any colour theme below).  When the carousel is below the navbar, the navigation arrows of the carousel are overlapping the above navbar, making it irresponsive (select HeaderFirst...).

I am sure a simple CSS trick could solve the problem.  Any idea?

Comment: You  need to wrap the `Navbar` with `container` and `row` class. Currently it starts with `<div class="col-md-12 text-center">`.

Comment: You can add a new `container` and `row` classes at the top of it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a column around your `navbar`; remove the "col-md-12" from the div above the `navbar`. See example.

```css
 @font-size-base: 18px;
 #map-container {
   height: 600px;
   width: 100%;
 }
 #minimap-container {
   min-height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .mini0,
 .mini1,
 .mini2,
 .mini3,
 .mini4,
 .mini5 {
   font-size: 9px;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 .mini0 {
   color: red;
 }
 .mini1 {
   color: grey;
 }
 .mini2 {
   color: orange;
 }
 .mini3 {
   color: green;
 }
 .mini4 {
   color: blue;
 }
 .mini5 {
   color: violet;
 }
 .icon16link {
   border: 0px;
   background-color: transparent;
   width: 16px;
   cursor: pointer;
   vertical-align: text-bottom;
 }
 .icon12link {
   border: 0px;
   background-color: transparent;
   width: 12px;
   cursor: pointer;
   vertical-align: text-bottom;
 }
 .iconlink {
   border: 0px;
   cursor: pointer;
   vertical-align: text-middle;
 }
 .iconXLink {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #dddddd;
   vertical-align: text-middle;
 }
 .iconNoLink {
   border: 0px;
   vertical-align: text-middle;
 }
 .minithumb {
   height: 24px;
 }
 .star {
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
 body {
   font-family: verdana;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
 }
 h1,
 h2,
 h3,
 h4,
 h5,
 h6 {} p {
   font-size: 1.25em;
   line-height: 1.6;
   color: #000;
 }
 hr {
   max-width: 400px;
   border-color: #999999;
 }
 .brand,
 .address-bar {
   display: none;
 }
 .navbar-brand {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 900;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 .navbar-nav {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
 }
 .img-full {
   min-width: 100%;
 }
 .brand-before,
 .brand-name {
   text-transform: capitalize;
 }
 .brand-before {
   margin: 15px 0;
 }
 .brand-name {
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 3em;
 }
 .tagline-divider {
   margin: 15px auto 3px;
   max-width: 250px;
   border-color: #999999;
 }
 .box {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px;
   background: #fff;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 }
 .intro-text {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 1.25em;
   font-weight: 400;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 .img-border {
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto 0;
   border: #999999 solid 1px;
 }
 .img-left {
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto 0;
 }
 footer {
   background: #fff;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 }
 footer p {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 50px 0;
 }
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .brand {
     display: inherit;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 30px 0 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 5em;
     font-weight: 700;
     line-height: normal;
     color: #fff;
   }
   .top-divider {
     margin-top: 0;
   }
   .img-left {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 25px;
   }
   .address-bar {
     display: inherit;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 0 40px;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 1.25em;
     font-weight: 400;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     color: #fff;
   }
   .navbar {
     border-radius: 0;
   }
   .navbar-header {
     display: none;
   }
   .navbar {
     min-height: 0;
   }
   .navbar-default {
     border: none;
     background: #fff;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
   }
   .nav>li>a {
     padding: 10px;
   }
   .navbar-nav>li>a {
     line-height: normal;
   }
   .navbar-nav {
     display: table;
     float: none;
     margin: 0 auto;
     table-layout: fixed;
     font-size: 1.0em;
   }
 }
 @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   .box:after {
     content: '';
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }
 }
 /* carousel */
 .carousel,
 .carousel-inner > .item {
   display: run-in;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto!important;
 }
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
 .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   line-height: 1;
 }
 .carousel-container {
   margin-left: 0;
 }
 .carousel-caption {
   z-index: 10;
 }
 /* special elements */
 .Prop_Body {} .Prop_Address {
   font-size: 1em;
 }
 .Prop_Copyright {
   font-size: 0.8em;
 }
 .Prop_Snapshot {
   padding: 6px;
 }
 .Prop_Highlights {
   padding: 6px;
 }
 .Prop_Review {
   padding: 6px;
 }
 .Prop_MiniMap {
   padding: 6px;
 }
 .Prop_SidePhotos {
   padding: 6px;
 }
 .Prop_Agent {
   padding: 6px;
 }
 .colLeft {
   padding-top: 0px;
 }
 .colCenter {
   padding-top: 0px;
 }
 .colRight {
   padding-top: 0px;
 }
 /* gallery */
 /* popup large picture */
 .ddimgtooltip {
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
   /* shadow for CSS3 capable browsers */
   -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
   -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background: grey;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2000;
   padding: 8px;
   word-wrap: normal;
   max-width: 480px;
 }
 .gallerythumb {
   margin-bottom: 16px;
   margin-right: 16px;
 }
 .mini1 {
   font-size: 0.8em;
 }
 /* main tags */
 body {
   background: #FFF;
 }
 /* whole screen bgn color */
 /* body { background: url('../xMedia/Bgn/Pool2.jpg') no-repeat center fixed; } */
 p {
   color: #666;
 }
 /* text font color */
 h1,
 h2,
 h3,
 h4,
 h5,
 h6,
 .h1,
 .h2,
 .h3,
 .h4,
 .h5,
 .h6 {
   color: #4190B0;
 }
 /* all titles font color */
 h2,
 .h2 {}
 /* h2 title font color */
 h3,
 .h3 {
   color: #A6A6A6;
 }
 /* h3 title font color */
 h4,
 .h4 {
   color: #cecece;
 }
 /* h4 title font color */
 h5,
 .h5 {}
 /* h5 title font color */
 h6,
 .h6 {}
 /* h6 title font color */
 /* navbar */
 .navbar-default {
   background: transparent;
 }
 /* navbar bgn color */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: #4190B0;
 }
 /* navbar item font color */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
   color: #39626F;
 }
 /* navbar item hover font color */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
   color: #39626F;
 }
 /* navbar item focus font color */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #4190B0;
 }
 /* active navbar item bgn & font color */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #39626F;
 }
 /* active navbar item hover bgn & font color */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #39626F;
 }
 /* active navbar item focus bgn & font color */
 /* components */
 .brand-name {
   color: #69A2C8;
 }
 /* brand-name font color */
 .brand-subname {
   color: #69A2C8;
 }
 /* brand-subname font color */
 .brand-strapline {
   color: #999;
 }
 /* brand-strapline font color */
 .Prop_Address {
   color: #888;
 }
 /* address font color */
 .Prop_Copyright {
   color: #999;
 }
 /* copyright font color */
 .Prop_Highlights,
 .Prop_Highlights p {
   background: #3673b8;
   color: #fff;
 }
 /* highlights bgn color */
 .Prop_Snapshot {
   background: #3673b8;
   color: #fff;
 }
 /* keyfigures bgn color */
 .Prop_Review,
 .Prop_Review p {
   background: #9EB8CF;
   color: #fff;
 }
 /* review bgn color */
 .Prop_Agent {
   background: #9EB8CF;
 }
 /* review bgn color */
 .Prop_MiniMap {
   border: 1px solid grey;
   background: #FFF;
 }
 /* minimap bgn color */
 .Prop_SidePhotos {
   background: #FFF;
 }
 /* sidephotos bgn color */
 .btn-info {
   background: #39626F;
   border-color: #39626F;
 }
 /* button bgn color */
 .reviewTitle {
   color: #fff;
 }
 .reviewAuthor {
   color: #cecece;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   font-style: italic;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .reviewMore {
   text-align: right;
   color: blue;
 }
 .guestbookTitle {
   color: #000;
   font-size: 1.2em;
 }
 .guestbookQuote {
   color: #000;
   font-size: 1.1em;
 }
 .guestbookAuthor {
   color: #cecece;
   font-size: 1em;
   font-style: italic;
 }
 .propertyName {
   color: #69A2C8;
   font-size: 1.4em;
 }
 .propertyStrapLine {
   color: #666;
   font-size: 1em;
   font-style: italic;
 }
 .propertyText {
   color: #888;
   font-size: 0.9em;
 }
 .owner {
   border: 0px solid red;
 }
 /* FONTS & SIZE */
 /* body */
 body {
   font-family: verdana;
 }
 /* titles */
 h1,
 h2,
 h3,
 h4,
 h5,
 h6,
 .h1,
 .h2,
 .h3,
 .h4,
 .h5,
 .h6 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-family: verdana;
 }
 h1,
 .h1 {
   font-size: 1.8em;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 h2,
 .h2 {
   font-size: 1.6em;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 h3,
 .h3 {
   text-transform: capitalize;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 h4,
 .h4 {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 h5,
 .h5 {
   font-size: 1.2em;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 h6,
 .h6 {
   font-size: 1.1em;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 /* paragraph */
 p {
   font-size: 1em;
   line-height: 1.6;
 }
 /* nav */
 .navbar-default {
   font-size: 1.05em;
   letter-spacing: 6px;
   text-weight: bold;
   text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 /* brand */
 .brand-name {
   font-family: times;
   font-size: 2.8em;
 }
 .brand-subname {
   font-family: times;
   font-size: 1em;
 }
 .brand-strapline {
   font-size: 1.4em;
 }
 /* image */
 .img-border {
   border: #999999 solid 1px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container Prop_Name" style="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <p class="brand-name">ShowCase <span class="brand-subname">beach house</span>

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<div class="container Prop_StrapLine" style="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <p class="brand-strapline">One of the best in Hyams - infinity pool and private beach access</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<!-- NAV BAR -->
<div class="text-center">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container Prop_NavBar" style="">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=home">home</a>

          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=features">features</a>

          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=activities">activities</a>

          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=gallery">gallery</a>

          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=rates">rates</a>

          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=guestbook">guestbook</a>

          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=map">map</a>

          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Template/index.php?Menu=contact">contact</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- BANNER -->
<div class="container Prop_Banner" style="">
  <div class="carousel-container">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://www.helloguest.com.au/Admin/zGetImageManip.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.helloguest.com.au%2FxMedia%2FPicture%2FBigPhotos%2FP000002%2FHG_000035.jpg&w=1200&h=480" alt="image #0">
          <div class="carousel-caption">Main : infinity pool - wines [&copy; ShowCase]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item ">
          <img src="http://www.helloguest.com.au/Admin/zGetImageManip.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.helloguest.com.au%2FxMedia%2FPicture%2FBigPhotos%2FP000002%2FHG_000035.jpg&w=1200&h=480" alt="image #1">
          <div class="carousel-caption">Aerial : aerial view [&copy; ShowCase]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item ">
          <img src="http://www.helloguest.com.au/Admin/zGetImageManip.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.helloguest.com.au%2FxMedia%2FPicture%2FBigPhotos%2FP000002%2FHG_000035.jpg&w=1200&h=480" alt="image #2">
          <div class="carousel-caption">Exterior : house - beach night [&copy; ShowCase]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item ">
          <img src="http://www.helloguest.com.au/Admin/zGetImageManip.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.helloguest.com.au%2FxMedia%2FPicture%2FBigPhotos%2FP000002%2FHG_000035.jpg&w=1200&h=480" alt="image #3">
          <div class="carousel-caption">Outdoors : north deck [&copy; ShowCase]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item ">
          <img src="../Admin/zGetImageManip.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.helloguest.com.au%2FxMedia%2FPicture%2FBigPhotos%2FP000002%2FHG_000051.jpg&w=1200&h=480" alt="image #4">
          <div class="carousel-caption">Outdoors : upper level - night [&copy; ShowCase]</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>

      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you!  BTW what is the meaning of "<!-- /.container -->"?

Comment: That's merely a comment stating the end of a container (or any section, etc); <!--something end--> If you search your templates you'll see it several times and the start of that section should also be a container class then.  See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to add "z-index: 9999;" to the style property of the carousal anchors.

The best way would be to completely differentiate the navbar and the carousal.